# RadGrid with MasterTableView

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I want to know how do I write the code behind for `RadGridTransactions_ItemDataBound`

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridTransactions" runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="RadGridTransactions_ItemDataBound" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both"  Height="70px" >
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowFilteringByColumn="false" ShowFooter="false" 
        DataKeyNames="TransactionID" Visible ="true">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonTransaction" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonTransaction_CheckedChanged" HeaderText="Closing Book Transaction" Visible ="true" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TransactionID" UniqueName="TransactionID" meta:resourcekey="TransactionID" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Transaction ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="practiceAreaText" UniqueName="practiceAreaText" meta:resourcekey="practiceAreaText" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Practice Area">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="mattertypecategory" UniqueName="mattertypecategory" meta:resourcekey="mattertypecategory" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Matter Type Category">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="matterTypeText" UniqueName="matterTypeText" meta:resourcekey="matterTypeText" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Matter Type">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="ClosingDate" UniqueName="ClosingDate" meta:resourcekey="ClosingDateTransaction" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Closing Date">
            </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
             <telerik:GridTemplateColumn meta:resourcekey="DealSheetStatus" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Deal Sheet Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Image runat="server" ID="RowImage" ImageUrl="../Images/cancel.png" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridImageColumn Visible="true" DataType="System.String" DataImageUrlFields="DealSheetStatus" meta:resourcekey="DealSheetStatus" 
                DataImageUrlFormatString="../Images/{0}"
                ImageAlign="Middle" >
            </telerik:GridImageColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ClosingBooks" UniqueName="ClosingBooks" meta:resourcekey="ClosingBooks" Visible ="true" HeaderText="Closing Book">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn
                Target="blank" UniqueName="MatterID" DataNavigateUrlFields="MatterID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString ="http://semtlweb1:8091/matterdetails.aspx?matterid={0}"
                Text="EDIT" meta:resourcekey="LinkDealSheet" HeaderText="Link To Data Sheet">
            </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: please provide full code of the page

Comment: afaik no, you don't need `RadGridTransactions_ItemDataBound` for `GridHyperLinkColumn`, your approach looks like adhere [this one](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-gridhyperlinkcolumn-datanavigateurlformatstring). And based on intuition, `http://semtlweb1:8091/matterdetails.aspx?matterid={0}`, the `{0}` part filled with `MatterID`. So, what was your problem? ps. `ItemDataBound` is best paired with `GridTemplateColumn` where you could put tons of controls there.

Comment: I can see the radgrid in the designer mode but when I run the application I can just see a box there are no columns inside it

Comment: Can someone please look into this?